# How do I chose a chunk of tags that are in between of two tags?

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

(and including the ending tag)

For example:

```xml
<xml>
  <a></a>
  <a><b></b></a>

  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a><c></c></a>

  <a></a>
  <a><b></b></a>
  <a><b></b></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a><b></b></a>
</xml>
```

I need these three `<a>` that are after the one that includes `<b>` and ending with the one that includes `<c>`.

Or rather "start from one with `<c>` and select back until you see one with `<b>` or end of document" that would be even better because there can be case with no 'start' `<b>` marker.

I need it to write an element-blocking rule for the uBlock Origin Chrome extension.

Comment: what version of XPath, please? It makes a big difference

Comment: also, please edit your question so that the example is actually well formed XML

Comment: @ConalTuohy I'm sorry I have no idea about the XPath version. I want to use it to block the page elements using [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm) browser extension. Probably it uses the Chrome's JS engine.

Comment: OK so it will be XPath version 1.0

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```xml
//a[c][1] | 
//a[c][1]/preceding-sibling::a
   [
      not(
         b or following-sibling::a[b]/following-sibling::a/c
      )
   ]
```

Explanation:

- the first `a` that contains a `c`, and also...
- the `a` elements that precede that `a`, so long as they don't themselves either:

  - contain a `b` or
  - have a following `a` that contains a `b` and which is followed by another `a` that contains a `c`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
//a[not(b)][c | following-sibling::*[./*][1][./c]]
```

It takes all not(b) which are either c (the ending) or "that the next tag that includes anything includes c".

Or:

```
//a[c or not(*) and following-sibling::*[*][1][./c]]
```